# InstrumentClusterRenderingService cannot recognize my navigation App

Tags: android, android-automotive

I am working on an AAOS (Android Automotive OS) platform. The OS version is 10.

I included "DirectRenderingCluster" in my car_product/build/car.mk as
`PRODUCT_PACKAGES += DirectRenderingCluster`.
In this App, there is a ClusterRenderingService, which implements [InstrumentClusterRenderingService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Car/+/refs/heads/android10-release/car-lib/src/android/car/cluster/renderer/InstrumentClusterRenderingService.java).

In InstrumentClusterRenderingService, it will try to gather some information of the suitable navigation App from the PackageManager. Originally, it will pick the [FakeClusterNavigationActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Car/+/refs/heads/android10-release/tests/EmbeddedKitchenSinkApp/AndroidManifest.xml) in EmbeddedKitchenSinkApp.

I want to replace the FakeClusterNavigationActivity with my own navigation App.
I mimicked it and made a similar activity.
However, I am getting error messages printed at line 153 and 299 of [InstrumentClusterRenderingService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Car/+/refs/heads/android10-release/car-lib/src/android/car/cluster/renderer/InstrumentClusterRenderingService.java).

What do I miss? What should I do to make the Car service recognize my App is an eligible navigation App for cluster? Thank you.

My AndroidManifest.xml looks like as follows. The targetSdkVersion is 29.

```
<manifest
    package="com.mytest.android"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system">
```

```
    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:persistent="false"
        android:name="com.mytest.android.NaviApp"
        android:label="@string/application_label"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon">
```

```
        <!-- Activity for cluster. Note that this is not the only activity in this App. -->
        <activity android:process=":map_surface"
            android:name=".MapSurfaceActivity"
            android:label="MapSurfaceActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:allowEmbedded="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.car.cluster.NAVIGATION"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Content provider for images (fake, not functional) -->
        <provider android:name=".cluster.ClusterContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mytest.android.cluster.clustercontentprovider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be Google's bug and has been fixed in the later code.

If the navigation app is launched as non-system user and is not installed for system user, this bug will occur.
In the original code, it uses system user's PackageManager to call `getPackageInfo()` and `queryIntentActivities()`. However, the navigation app is not installed for system user (maybe being put in the blacklist), so it won't be found.

To fix, `PackageManager.MATCH_ANY_USER` flag should be used in `getPackageInfo()`, and `queryIntentActivitiesAsUser()` should be used in stead of `queryIntentActivities()`.

I don't know what commits fixed them but they are shown in the master branch.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Car/+/master/car-lib/src/android/car/cluster/renderer/InstrumentClusterRenderingService.java